# web script language tag definition

Tags: language-agnostic

I am new to web development. It's easy to see a lot tag starting with:

```
<%=
<%!
<%@
```

What are these tag called? Is it from any specific scripting language? Can I find the reference on w3schools? Please help, thanks.

Comment: I am actually looking into a aspx code. Just found this page http://quickstart.developerfusion.co.uk/QuickStart/aspnet/doc/pages/syntax.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That looks like [JavaServer Pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages). W3Schools doesn't have anything on it, but with the name you should be able to Google it and find a lot.